# Nifi put Geoip to Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, apache-nifi

I have a JSON

```json
{
  "ipaddress" : "92.63.197.86",
  "syslog.sender" : "10.10.10.1",
  "ipaddress.geo.lookup.micros" : "16240",
  "mime.type" : "application/json",
  "ipaddress.geo.longitude" : "37.6068",
  "uuid" : "24300490-2676-4b9c-8838-7f6ee2567a97",
  "ipaddress.geo.country" : "Russia",
  "syslog.protocol" : "UDP",
  "ipaddress.accuracy" : "1000",
  "path" : "./",
  "filename" : "24300490-2676-4b9c-8838-7f6ee2567a97",
  "name" : "Corp01 input",
  "syslog.port" : "2514",
  "ipaddress.geo.country.isocode" : "RU",
  "ipaddress.geo.latitude" : "55.7386"
}
```

When i want PutElasticsearchHttp

[image]

and I get an error

> PutElasticsearchHttp[id=441efd2b-017f-1000-fc76-fa64b799e680] Failed
> to process
> StandardFlowFileRecord[uuid=7418835e-8a90-4607-a2ec-8372c3b8a2c6,claim=StandardContentClaim
> [resourceClaim=StandardResourceClaim[id=1646495020360-551,
> container=default, section=551], offset=845802,
> length=488],offset=0,name=7418835e-8a90-4607-a2ec-8372c3b8a2c6,size=488]
> due to can't merge a non object mapping [ipaddress] with an object
> mapping, transferring to failure

What is wrong? how to solve it

Comment: what does `GET mt-geoip/_mapping` give you?

Comment: `GET /mt-geoip/_mapping`

```json
{
  "mt-geoip" : {
    "mappings" : { }
  }
}
```

He did not create a mapping

Comment: If I put new index

``` json
PUT /mt-geoip
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "ipaddress": { "type": "ip" },
      "syslog.sender": { "type": "ip" },
      "ipaddress.geo.lookup.micros": { "type": "integer" },
      "mime.type": { "type": "text" },
      "ipaddress.geo.longitude": { "type": "float" },

```

Output

``` json
  "error" : {
    "root_cause" : [
      {
        "type" : "mapper_parsing_exception",
        "reason" : "Failed to parse mapping [_doc]: mapper [ipaddress] cannot be changed from type [ip] to [ObjectMapper]"

```

Comment: according to this last error message, there must be a mapping already existing for index mt-geoip (ipaddress is type ip, but you ingest it with type object). If data can be cleared, I'd drop the index and let it and its mapping recreate automatically by your nifi ingest.